# Why are bootstrap classes not working after I import enqueue it in my functions.php file using WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

In my child theme functions PHP file, I have the following code:

```
<?php
add_action( ‘wp_enqueue_scripts’, ‘enqueue_child_theme_styles’, PHP_INT_MAX);
function enqueue_child_theme_styles() {
wp_enqueue_style( ‘parent-style’, get_template_directory_uri().’/style.css’ );
}


//  IMPORT BOOTSTRAP CDN 

function my_scripts_enqueue() {
wp_register_script( 'bootstrap-js', '://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js', array('jquery'), NULL, true );
wp_register_style( 'bootstrap-css', '://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css', false, NULL, 'all' );

wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrap-js' );
wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap-css' );
}

// END BOOTSTRAP IMPORT

?>
```

However, when I try to use a simple bootstarp class like `col-sm-4` I do not get the column layout on my page. It seems, bootstrap is not being loaded. I'm using the optimizer theme, but I don't think that matters.

In any event. I've scoured there many WP support forums and to no avail have I had success. Custom css is working in my child theme style file but this is not working in the functions file. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing 2 things....

1. You function `my_scripts_enqueue` doesn't seem to be called anywhere, just call it inside your `enqueue_child_theme_styles` function or add another hook function call for it.
2. In `'://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/boo...` we don't start with `:` just with `//` ;-)

Your code should look something like this...

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_child_theme_styles', PHP_INT_MAX);
function enqueue_child_theme_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri().'/style.css' );
    my_scripts_enqueue();
}

//  IMPORT BOOTSTRAP CDN
function my_scripts_enqueue() {
    wp_register_script( 'bootstrap-js', '//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js', array('jquery'), NULL, true );
    wp_register_style( 'bootstrap-css', '//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css', false, NULL, 'all' );

    wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrap-js' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap-css' );
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help! I really appreciate it! Sorry for the slow reply. I'll be able to vote up with just a few more rep points.

Comment: Besides voting up, you should also accept the answer by clicking the check mark below voting arrows so that other user know that this question is answered ;-)

Comment: @shramee could you please help me with my question asked on stackoverflow.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68415636/style-css-and-bootstrap-cdn-not-loading-in-function-php